# Postgres with clause to substring large char column into rows

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression, recursive-query

Issue: I have limitations in the code that I am writing that won't read in columns > 4K bytes

Want: Turn a single row into multiple rows with a new max length and have the ordinal to keep them in order.

I have done this activity in DB2 previously using the with clause and a recursive query, I am trying to convert the code to work with Postgres. I don't have as much Postgres experience to know if there is a better way to do this.

To start I have a table

```
Create table test_long_text (
   test_id numeric(12,0) NOT NULL,
   long_text varchar(64000)
)
```

Here is the query I have been trying to write and failed.

```
WITH RECURSIVE rec(test_id, len, ord, pos) as (
   select test_id, octet_length(long_text), 1, 1 from test_long_text
   union all
   select test_id, len, ord+1, pos+4096 from rec where len >=4096)
select A.test_id, ord, substr(long_text, pos, 4096) from test_long_text A
inner join rec using (test_id)
order by A.test_id, ord
```

Currently, I get an error negative substring length not allowed or it hangs indefinitely.

Expected Results: Where the text is chunks of text at a max of 4096 bytes long. pretend ABC is a longer string.

```
+--------------+
| ID |ORD|TEXT |
| 1  |1  |ABC  |
+--------------+
| 2  |1  |ABC  |
+--------------+
| 2  |2  |DEF  |
+--------------+
| 3  |1  |ABC  |
+--------------+
| 3  |2  |DEF  |
+--------------+
| 3  |3  |GHI  |
+--------------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This example shows how to split values of text column into 3-characters parts:

```
with t(x) as (values('1234567890abcdef'::text), ('qwertyuiop'))
select *, substring(x, f.p, 3)
from t, generate_series(1, length(x), 3) with ordinality as f(p, i);
```

```
┌──────────────────┬────┬───┬───────────┐
│        x         │ p  │ i │ substring │
├──────────────────┼────┼───┼───────────┤
│ 1234567890abcdef │  1 │ 1 │ 123       │
│ 1234567890abcdef │  4 │ 2 │ 456       │
│ 1234567890abcdef │  7 │ 3 │ 789       │
│ 1234567890abcdef │ 10 │ 4 │ 0ab       │
│ 1234567890abcdef │ 13 │ 5 │ cde       │
│ 1234567890abcdef │ 16 │ 6 │ f         │
│ qwertyuiop       │  1 │ 1 │ qwe       │
│ qwertyuiop       │  4 │ 2 │ rty       │
│ qwertyuiop       │  7 │ 3 │ uio       │
│ qwertyuiop       │ 10 │ 4 │ p         │
└──────────────────┴────┴───┴───────────┘
```

You can simply adapt it to your data.